# Git - easiest way to see diff with previous version if I have the sha

Tags: git, git-diff

A colleague of mine checked in some changes to Git, and I want to see exactly what those changes were.  In other words, the diff between his check-in and its parent.

What seemed logical to me was to run this command:

```
git diff shaOfHisCheckIn
```

But this didn't work.  It appears to show the diff between that SHA and my current working copy.

What's the correct command to show the diff between a given SHA and its parent?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`git show` is your friend:

```
git show shaOfHisCheckIn
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need, and it's easy to remember and to type.

Comment: You're welcome! It works for tags too by the way (`git show <tag>`) - it's a really useful command.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to view the diff visually in `kdiff3`, `meld`, `kompare`, `xxdiff`, `tkdiff`, `diffuse`…

```
git difftool --dir-diff shaOfHisCheckIn^!

git difftool --tool=meld --dir-diff shaOfHisCheckIn^!

git difftool -t meld -d shaOfHisCheckIn^!
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
git diff shaOfHisCheckIn^ shaOfHisCheckIn
```

or

```
git diff shaOfHisCheckIn{^,}
```

Answer (score 2):

`git diff shaOfHisCheckIn shaOfHisCheckIn^`

Comment: Isn't [Vinoth Gopi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128131/git-easiest-way-to-see-diff-with-previous-version-if-i-have-the-sha-1-hash/6128240#6128240) more appropriate (the order)?