# Why doesn't `git diff` invoke external diff tool?

Tags: git, diff, meld

In my repository, if I type

```
$ git diff some-file
```

or

```
$ git difftool some-file
```

I get the in-terminal diff display. I think this should not happen, because I have set up an external diff tool, as shown by the output of `git config -l`:

```
$ git config -l
user.name=blah blah
user.email=blah blah
http.sslverify=true
diff.external=/home/daniel/bin/git-diff  <--This is the important line
push.default=simple
core.filemode=false
core.editor=gedit
alias.tree=log --all --graph --decorate=short --color --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) %C(auto)%d%C(reset)
         %C(black)[%cr]%C(reset)  %x09%C(black)%an: %s %C(reset)'
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=https://daniel@skynet/git/pyle.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.daniel.remote=origin
branch.daniel.merge=refs/heads/daniel
```

The git-diff file referenced in the `diff.external` line looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

meld $2 $5
```

Why doesn't `git diff` invoke meld?

I get the same behaviour if I set things up so that `git config -l` has the following line:

```
diff.tool = meld
```

or

```
diff.external = usr/bin/meld
```

**Note**: Other repositories on my machine don't have this problem.

Related, but not equivalent, SO questions:

1. [What is the difference between `git diff` and `git difftool`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950052/what-is-the-difference-between-git-diff-and-git-difftool)
2. [Cannot make git diff use diff.external for external diff tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883901/cannot-make-git-diff-use-diff-external-for-external-diff-tool)

Comment: Why are you using the second and fifth arguments?

Comment: @merlin2011: My understanding is that git diff passes seven arguments into the external diff tool and that meld only needs two of them.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I get the in-terminal diff display. I this should not happen, because I have set up an external diff tool

Yes, it should: diff.external *is* for "in-terminal diff display".

(from [`git config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.0.0))

```
diff.external
```

> If this config variable is set, **diff generation is not performed using the internal diff machinery, but using the given command**.
> Can be overridden with the `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` environment variable.
> The command is called with parameters as described under "git Diffs" in git(1). Note: if you want to use an external diff program only on a subset of your files, you might want to use [gitattributes(5)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/gitattributes.html) instead.

The [question you link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22884673/6309) explains why `meld` wouldn't be able to play the role of an "external diff".

[Viewing a diff visually with another tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24963817/6309) is done with:

```
git difftool --dir-diff shaOfHisCheckIn^!
git difftool --tool=meld --dir-diff shaOfHisCheckIn^!
git difftool -t meld -d shaOfHisCheckIn^!
```

`meld` can be configured on Windows as a difftool: see "[Git Diff and Meld on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20401270/6309)".

---

If you wanted to configure meld for git diff, you could [(on Ubuntu) use the `diff.external`, but with a wrapper script](http://www.wiredforcode.com/blog/2011/06/04/git-with-meld-diff-viewer-on-ubuntu/):

> create a file called `git-diff.sh`, using the following content:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> meld "$2" "$5" > /dev/null 2>&1
> ```
>
> Save this to a location such as `/usr/local/bin`, giving it executable rights:
>
> ```
> $ sudo mv git-diff.sh /usr/local/bin/
> $ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/git-diff.sh
> ```
>
> The final step is to open your `$HOME/.gitconfig` file and add the following few lines:
>
> ```
> [diff]
>         external = /usr/local/bin/git-diff.sh
> ```
>
> The next time you type `git diff` in a Git project with changes, Meld will be launched showing you a split-pane diff viewer.
> Note that you are required to close the open instance of meld before the next diff viewer is opened.

---

[will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108350/will) notes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966271/why-doesnt-git-diff-invoke-external-diff-tool/24967334?noredirect=1#comment120956884_24967334):

> That wrapper script works great on my Ubuntu system.
>
> I did discover a gottcha: I detached the `meld` command as so:
>
> ```
> meld "$2" "$5" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
> ```
>
> Kept failing to open the `$2` file (tempory file).
> What happens? Well, `git` removes `$2` once the wrapper exits.
> My suggestion, if you wish to detach copy the `tmp` file, invoke `meld` and remove `tmp` file yourself.

will proposes [the gist gist-meld.bash](https://gist.github.com/aplatypus/5ac6ba4bab2b145a3a24ef9760b836b4), using `meld --newtab`, as [seen here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1058344/5470):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#  * expects meld to be on your default PATH
#
function detach_meld()
{
    local f1="/tmp/mld1-$(basename "$1")"
    local f2="/tmp/mld2-$(basename "$2")"
    
##  echo "f1 = ${f1}"
##  echo "f2 = ${f2}"

    cp "$1" "${f1}"
    cp "$2" "${f2}"
#
    (meld  --newtab  "${f1}" "${f2}" ; rm  "${f1}"  "${f2}" ) > /dev/null 2>&1  &    
}

detach_meld  "$2"  "$5"
```

Comment: `git difftool` seems to be the solution. I tried using a wrapper script but for some reason that doesn't work.

Comment: That wrapper script works great on my Ubuntu system.  I did discover a _gottcha_.  I detached the `meld` command as so: `meld "$2" "$5" > /dev/null 2>&1 &`.  Kept failing to open the `$2` file (tempory file).  What happens?  Well, `git` removes `$2` once the wrapper exits.  My suggestion, if you wish to detach copy the tmp file, invoke `meld` and remove tmp file yourself.

Comment: @will Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC .. Me again.  Today  I discovered the branch diff operation: `git diff main...mybranch` -- It compares two temporary files when you use a `meld` wrapper script.  One is always blank for the same "temporary file" reason above.   I changed my wrapper script to make two copy temp files -- **Works**!!

Comment: @will Great! Do you have a link to your wrapper script?

Comment: I put up a gist: [git-meld.bash](https://gist.github.com/aplatypus/5ac6ba4bab2b145a3a24ef9760b836b4).  If you actually do compare branches, be prepared for a great number of meld windows to pop-up.  One for each file in the branch.  Please leave a commend if you know how open the files as tabs in meld?

Comment: @will Maybe by using the meld `--newtab` option ? Seen here in the context of bzr: https://askubuntu.com/a/1058344/5470: see if you can adapt it to git difftool option.

Comment: @VonC ... Great idea.  I was concerned that the temp files might get lost or overritten -- No Worries.  It works smoothly opening all the files and I feel it is faster using ` --newtab` .  Gist updated: [git-meld.bash](https://gist.github.com/aplatypus/5ac6ba4bab2b145a3a24ef9760b836b4).  Thanks.  Great suggestion.

Answer (score 16):

It seems that `git diff` (at least, as of `git` version `1.7.12.4`) will not run anything other than the internal, console-only diff on a file which is in the "both modified" state. `git mergetool` works on such files, though.

Comment: This is still true with git version 1.9.1,  What an annoyance!   I just wasted an hour trying to figure out why my git config settings for difftool had suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Still the case on `git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)`. The console only 3-way-merge workflow is a pretty big pain point. There's really a huge shortage of capable console native diff tools.  I believe the path i will take is to allow git to dump the conflict markers into the files, and then use a simple tool, that I will write, to processes these to generate readable diff outputs.

Comment: Aha! @trebor-rude, you just saved my sanity with wondering why none of my difftool selections were working

Answer (score 2):

I usually just want to check whether the changes I'm about to check in are correct. So I followed the procedure suggested [here](http://www.wiredforcode.com/blog/2011/06/04/git-with-meld-diff-viewer-on-ubuntu/) (similar to the one noted by VonC). However, running `git difftool` still didn't open meld. I then created an alias:

```
alias git-diff='git difftool $(git rev-parse HEAD)'
```

Save this in your .bashrc or .zshrc or the corresponding config for your shell. This essentially compares the state of the branch with the previous commit on the branch.

Do a `git-diff` to see changes on a file per file basis or `git-diff --dir` to see all changes in a directory view.